# I need to use COUNT in Access SQL, and calculate average price

Tags: sql, count, average

I have two tables:

```
   PRODUCT           ITEM
- PRODUCT_ID      - ITEM_ID
- PRODUCT_DESC    - STORE_ID
- VENDOR_CODE     - PRODUCT_ID
                  - ITEM_PRICE
```

The PRODUCT table is for listing the details of each product that is sold at the store, and the ITEM table is essentially the inventory of each story, listing what products are in each store and their prices.

I want to have a function which returns the product description, number of items (COUNT), and the average price of the items for all items of the same product type. However, I also want to have the condition that only products with more than 10 items are to be listed in the output.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_DESC AS Description,
       COUNT(ITEM.ITEM_ID) AS Count,
       AVG(ITEM.ITEM_PRICE) AS [Average Price]
FROM PRODUCT, ITEM
WHERE PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ITEM.PRODUCT_ID
AND COUNT(ITEM.ITEM_ID) > 10;
```

I am using Access SQL, I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: That last edit, i think you wanted to do `PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ITEM.PRODUCT_ID`. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use INNER JOIN instead of the obsolete multiple tables without join like:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_DESC AS Description,
COUNT(*) AS CountItems,
AVG(ITEM.ITEM_PRICE) AS [Average Price]
FROM ITEM
INNER JOIN PRODUCT
ON ITEM.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCT_DESC
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use aggregate functions such as `COUNT` or `AVG`, you have to `GROUP BY` the non aggregate column, and to validate the `COUNT`, use `HAVING COUNT`. You should do something like this (untested):

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_DESC AS Description,
       COUNT(ITEM.ITEM_ID) AS Count,
       AVG(ITEM.ITEM_PRICE) AS [Average Price]
FROM PRODUCT, ITEM
WHERE PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ITEM.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY PRODUCT.PRODUCT_DESC
HAVING COUNT(ITEM.ITEM_ID) > 10
```

Comment: The having clause produces a syntax error, but everything else works. If I take it out, it returns everything correctly, except that it will return all the products, not just the ones with more than ten items.

Comment: Never mind, it works when you switch the HAVING and GROUP BY clauses around.